# How to use parameter, function in Python

Tags: python, function, parameters

I want to use a function in Python. I would like to pass "Drill" to the parameter of the dataupdate function that I defined but it is not working. What do I have to do? The code at the bottom is what I want.
Thanks.

```
def dataupdate(plant):
    int('fr_'+plant) = open('plant.txt', 'r')
    to_plant2 = fr_plant.read()
    if to_plant != to_plant2:
        print(to_plant2)
        fr_plant.close()
        int_out_plant2 = int(to_plant2, 2)
        OUT_plant2 = 255 - int_out_plant2
        print(OUT_plant2)
        Out_plant.set_value(OUT_plant2)
    to_plant = to_plant2

dataupdate('Drill')







fr_Drill = open('Drill.txt', 'r')
    to_Drill2 = fr_Drill.read()
    if to_Drill !=to_Drill2:
        print(to_Drill2)
        fr_Drill.close()
        int_out_Drill2 = int(to_Drill2, 2)
        OUT_Drill2 = 255-int_out_Drill2
        print(OUT_Drill2)
        Out_Drill.set_value(OUT_Drill2)
    to_Drill=to_Drill2
```

Comment: Whenever there is a "_it is not working_", please include the error message you're getting (if any) or the actual behaviour, and include the expected behaviour. Down to your code, `int('fr_'+plant) = open('plant.txt', 'r')` is not valid syntax. It's not clear what you're trying to do... perhaps you simply meant `fr_plant = open('plant.txt', 'r')` instead?

Comment: I got the following error.   
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: What variable name do you think you are assigning to? It doesn't really matter *what* the name of that variable is; it certainly doesn't have to depend the value of `plant`. Just write `f = open('plant.txt', 'r')` and use `f` consistently.

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code, you should fix those first then repost your proper code and ask specifically what you are looking help on.

Comment: I basically want the code on the bottom part (The part that starts with   fr_Drill = open('Drill.txt', 'r') ) using the dataupdate(plant) function. I tried fr_plant = open('plant.txt', 'r')  but I got "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'plant.txt'". The file I have is Drill.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you are passing the parameter correctly, but your function will not work with it. The problem is in the line

```py
int('fr_'+plant) = open('plant.txt', 'r')
```

With `open('plant.txt', 'r')` you are not opening the text file with the name of the variable saved in plant, but the actual file 'plant.txt', which probably doesn't exist, also the statement itself isn't valid. You can try something like

```py
open(str(plant) + '.txt', 'r')
```

instead. This should open the text file with the variable name saved in plant, not 'plant.txt'.

Feel free to ask any question that may arise.

PS: Please work on your variable naming, keep to one style (e.g. only capital or only small, not partially capital like OUT_Drill2) and try to avoid enumrating the variables (like, again, with OUT_Drill2). This would help a lot with readability, which is a key idea of python.

PPS: As mentioned in the comments, there are also other errors in your code.